# r : create list of network matrices

Tags: r, matrix, network-analysis

I want to create a list of network matrices, split by *project*. My data is structured like a this.

```
Project Person_i  Person_j   Value
1       A         B          6
1       B         A          6
2       A         B          4
2       A         C          5
2       B         A          4
2       B         C          9
2       C         A          5
2       C         B          9
```

I know how to split the data, and how to create binary edge-lists. However, I just can't figure out how to create the matrices with valued data.

Specifically, I want my data to look like this

List$1:

```
  A B
A 0 6
B 6 0
```

List$2:

```
  A B C
A 0 4 5
B 4 0 9
C 5 9 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try in base `R`:

```
#just in case the columns are factors
df[,2:3]<-lapply(df[,2:3],as.character)
f<-function(x) {
  pers<-unique(unlist(x[,2:3]))
  res<-matrix(0,length(pers),length(pers),dimnames=list(pers,pers))
  res[as.matrix(x[,2:3])]<-x[,4]
  res
}
lapply(split(df,df$Project),f)
#$`1`
#   A B
# A 0 6
# B 6 0
#$`2`
#  A B C
#A 0 4 5
#B 4 0 9
#C 5 9 0
```

With `reshape2` it's easier:

```
require(reshape2)
lapply(split(df,df$Project),
       function(x) acast(x,Person_i ~ Person_j,value.var="Value",fill=0))
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you think that this will work in a very large dataset with strong variations in cluster (i.e., project) size?

Comment: You need to try. Use a subset of the dataset if you are worried about problems and see how it reacts.

Comment: Can't tell without looking at your data. You have a strange double comma in the error message: are you sure that you didn't make a typo? How many columns there are in your dataset? Why you didn't show an example that better reflects your actual data?